# Django super class's manager has unwanted objects of child class via ForeignKey

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

```
class Dad(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Son(Dad):
    dad = models.ForeignKey(Dad, related_name='sons')



>>> dad = Dad(name="Leonid")
>>> dad.save()
>>> Dad.objects.all()
[<Dad: Leonid>]
>>> son = Son(name='Jason')
>>> dad.sons.add(son)
>>> Dad.objects.all()
[<Dad: Leonid>, <Dad: Jason>]
>>> Son.objects.all()
[<Son: Jason>]
```

I don't want to have Jason object in Dad's manager. I don't want to use custom managers to filter only dads. Is there an elegant way of not including objects of a child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending `Dad` to create your `Son` model, which is incorrect in your case. Currently your code means that every `Son` is also a `Dad`. Change your class definition to:

```
class Son(models.Model):
```

You can read more about [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) and [foreign key relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) which are different concepts which you seem to be confusing.